# How to delete item from a slice?

Tags: go, slice

Lets say we have a slice of string `["a" , "b", "c"]`, what is the idiomatic way to delete "b" from the slice when the input is `"b"`.

In order language, this seem be fairly easy. But when it comes to Go, it seems a little bit unclear for a beginner Gopher.

Comment: There's a very nice [wiki page](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks) that has a lot of slice tricks. In your case, you'd have to find the index of the element first. Also think about what happens if the element is present more than once

Comment: So these function is not included the sdk?